# Python/Selenium - Struggling to click on a button in a Navbar

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automation, navbar

I'm fairly new to Selenium and trying to automate login to this site (https://eudravigilance-human.ema.europa.eu/#/), but for the life of me cannot figure out how to click on the drop down button on the navbar.

Here is my current code

```
from selenium import webdriver;
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= 'C:\\Users\jpaddick\Python Extentions\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://eudravigilance-human.ema.europa.eu/#/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/nav/div/div[1]/button')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/nav/div/div[1]/button').click()
```

This is basically the code im running for another project so I don't think the syntax is wrong.

It doesnt seem to be sitting in an Iframe that I can switch to. Trying to click on the hidden login button directly doesn't seem to yield any results. No luck when using firefox instead and disabling the javascript on the site renders it inoperable.

Any ideas guys, as always im expecting something super simple that I forgot about :)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me

```
from selenium import webdriver;
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome() # Removed your executable path so it would work on my laptop
driver.get("https://eudravigilance-human.ema.europa.eu/#/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/nav/div/div[1]/button"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(., 'Login')]"))).click()
```

Notice how I combine the `wait.until` and `.click()` methods, this works because `wait.until` in this case returns a web element

Comment: Hmm... Good to know it should work, im getting an error though


</button> is not clickable at point (982, 34). Other element would receive the click: 
<div modal-render="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope ng-animate in-remove in-remove-active" modal-animation-class="fade" modal-in-class="in" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-click="close($event)" modal-window="modal-window" size="sm" index="0" animate="animate" modal-animation="true" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;">...</div>

Comment: Im thinking maybe its being blocked by the "your browser is being controlled by an external program" thingy

Comment: I checked and I cannot see any element that describes your error. Is there a pop-up / modal or something? The "your browser is being controlled by an external program" thingy sits above the page and doesn't affect the html

Comment: I just stuck in a time.sleep(10) and it works fine, so i dont know.   If its not the browser control overlay then maybe its the order it loads in the elements.

Comment: Heres my new code, Sorry I dont know how to format it in comments 'from selenium import webdriver; import time from selenium import webdriver;  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= 'C:\\Users\jpaddick\Python Extentions\chromedriver.exe') driver.get("eudravigilance-human.ema.europa.eu/#/"); time.sleep(10)  driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/nav/div/div[1]/butt‌​on').click()

Comment: Did you try my code? I don't see `wait` in your new code. It's better to use `wait` than `time.sleep()`

Comment: Yeah, i ran your code verbatim and received the above error, ive just ran it again now but with the time.sleep(10) after the driver.get command and it works.  I would use the wait command but i didnt know how to just wait for 10 seconds as apposed to waiting for a particular trigger.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the **`Nav Bar`** and then click on the **`Login`** link you can use the following code block :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='navbar-toggle collapsed' and @type='button']/span[@class='sr-only']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@class='menu-workspace']/a[contains(text(),'Login')]"))).click()
```